# Trouble understanding how to run commands automatically at systemstartup

Tags: command-line, games, startup

Ive been reading most top results about how to run@startup scripts on linux.

I have been running a homeserver for videogames and i would like to create something myself.

Not sure what it is called.  But lets call it a script for reference.

I would like to be able to create a script that can run certain commands when my linux-server updates and/or reboots.

it seems to do that quite often (which is good i believe)

atm I have made a config.txt file for a game called Terraria
This txt file contains wich world and game-settings the game is suppose to start with.
And it also has a rule set on when it cannot find -said world to autocreate a new one with certain parameters.

----description---

So I have created a file with the command:

```
touch startup.sh
```

I have create the script in the same folder where the game file are

this is what have write inside the startup.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
@reboot screen -S Terraria ./TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config serverconfig.txt
```

when I remove the @reboot I can execute command ./startup.sh
and it opens a screen called Terraria and runs the game with its config rules.

I cannot find a simple explanation that shows how to run a command at startup

I am pretty sure it comes down to the proper search, i believe the anywhere I am looking for already written somewhere.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is it a server (no GUI) or a desktop?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: when i use command: crontab -e 
This is when i have:

0 4 * * * /home/administrator/minecraftbe/Survival/restart.sh 2>&1
0 4 * * * /home/administrator/minecraftbe/SurvivalCraft/restart.sh 2>&1
0 4 * * * /home/administrator/minecraft/restart.sh 2>&1
0 4 * * * /home/administrator/minecraftbe/KlinkerCraft/restart.sh 2>&1

@reboot screen -S Terraria /home/administrator/terraria/1436/Linux/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config serverconfig.txt

Comment: Do a bit of Googling because LOTS of folks have asked Minecraft Server questions here, and there are some great answers already. Consider using systemd instead of crontab. There is a greater learning curve, but systemd permits monitoring and safe easy control for stopping/restarting the server.

Comment: Please don't do it like this. Make a SYSTEMD service so you can start/stop/restart Takes a 5 minutes to create from a skeleton service. Maybe 10 for a 1st timer ;-)

Comment: I added an example. Not sure if it is perfect, tweak the command to your liking. And as stated: took roughly 5 minutes ;) It will be a lot more useful than a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!/bin/bash` belongs to bash scripting.
`@reboot` belongs to crontab.

You can try using crontab to see if it can run the program that you want to.

In order to add a cronjob, you need to run `crontab -e` and then add your job to the end of the file, the line you'll need will look like this;

```
@reboot screen -S Terraria /path/to/the/server/folder/TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config serverconfig.txt
```

Comment: Does that mean the start.sh is what you call a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description=Terraria Server

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/terraria/
ExecStart=screen -S Terraria ./TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 -config serverconfig.txt nogui
User=Terraria
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- change the WorkingDirectory to what you want. I guessed that one
- the command I used from your example.
- save this as `/etc/systemd/system/terraria.service`
- you can add things like a socket to it so you can send commands to the service.

Control:

```
sudo systemctl start|stop|restart terraria  # Starts/stops/restarts
sudo systemctl status terraria  # shows the status of the service
sudo journalctl -u terraria -f   # shows the server log
```

And the part you are having trouble with: you enable or disable the service on startup with ...

```
sudo systemctl enable terraria.service
sudo systemctl disable terraria.service
```